# Understanding .NET Assembly Reference Differences

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I have two nearly identical DLLS (for the same open source project) - one was pre-compiled, and one was compiled locally by my own compiler (Xamarin Studio/Mono).

The DLL I compiled isn't working with the application that's supposed to be using it (while the pre-built one does), so I grabbed a decompiler to see if I can track down any differences (file sizes were slightly different):

[image]

I suspect the reference differences might be the problem.  The TOP one is the manually compiled dll.  How can I resolve this and make the references identical to the bottom dll's?  I've tried using the Mono/.NET 3.5 option in the settings, but it resulted in errors complaining about **default parameter specifiers** in a bunch of places, so it seems as if it's *meant* to be compiled w/4.0.  Here's a cap of the build settings options (only the Mono/.NET 4.0 option works):

[image]

What's causing the differences in assembly references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft introduces the multi-targeting feature in its C# compiler, so that C# 4/5 compiler (csc.exe) can generate .NET 2.0/3.0/3.5 compatible assemblies. That's how the pre-compiled assembly comes from.

Unfortunately it is a long time issue for MonoDevelop, that it does not support such multi-targeting. For example, you cannot choose Mono/.NET 3.5 and expect Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop to use the latest mcs compiler. It always uses the one for .NET 3.5 profile, and fails to compile if you use any C# 4/5 syntax.

You might try to use xbuild at terminal to compile, as xbuild does support multi-targeting. However, you might come across xbuild issues, as it is not yet as capable as MSBuild.